# PHP order by another table with added count

Tags: php, sql, select, count

How do order by another table's column and get the count from  other table column so I can order by that.

For example:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM photos, views WHERE photos.unqid = views.photoid ORDER BY CAST(views.id AS SIGNED)";
```

I want to add the views to  the photos. So that photos are order by the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following

```
SELECT p.*, v.*, COUNT(v.photoid) as nb_views
FROM photos p, views v
WHERE p.unqid = v.photoid
GROUP BY v.photoid
ORDER BY nb_views
```